# haml formbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, formbuilder

I'm converting an old program over to haml and I've got a problem with my custom formbuilder.  The problem is simply adding a line feed between a fields label and input tag.

Here is the original FormBuilder:

```
# Custom FormBuilder
class SuperFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

  # Create an array of helpers to override with our label builder
  helpers = field_helpers +
            %w{calendar_date_select date_select datetime_select time_select} +
            %w{collection_select select country_select time_zone_select} -
            %w{hidden_field label fields_for} # Don't decorate these

  helpers.each do |name|

    define_method(name) do |field, *args|

      # Get the hash option (EG the field involved)
      options = args.extract_options!

      # Create a label for that field
      label = label(field, options[:label], :class => options[:label_class])

      # Create an inline error
      error = error_message_on(field)

      # Wrap label in paragraph, include the original helper EG: text-field
      @template.content_tag(:p, label + "<br />" + super + error)  #wrap with a paragraph
    end
  end

  # Override the submit button
  def submit
    # Calculate custom text for submit button.
    prefix = object.new_record? ? "Create" : "Update"

    # Wrap submit button in paragraph tags and add custom text.
    @template.content_tag(:p,super(prefix, :id => "apply" ))
  end
end
```

If I use a %br where that <br /> is that doesn't work at all.  Is there a way to change this over to haml nicely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you just use `tag("br")`?

Comment: After playing around with it for a while I've discovered this works:

@template.content_tag(:p, label + @template.tag("br") + super + error)

Is there a way to minimise this a little?

Comment: @map7 Eight years after there is (still) the possibility of using `concat`.